# How to get values this variable in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a bad query.database admin is asking me to optimize this query but I don't know where this query is used because I can't find the value of SYS_B_N variable.how can I find the value of this variable ?

```
SELECT 
    NVL(SUM("A1"."SALDO_EQUIVAL_OUT"),:"SYS_B_0") 
FROM 
    "ACCOUNTS" "A1" 
WHERE 
    SUBSTR("A1"."CODE",:"SYS_B_1",:"SYS_B_2") LIKE :"SYS_B_3" 
    AND SUBSTR("A1"."CODE",:"SYS_B_4",:"SYS_B_5")<>:"SYS_B_6" 
    AND SUBSTR("A1"."CODE",:"SYS_B_7",:"SYS_B_8")=:"SYS_B_9"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the query in the v$sql view. In the object_id column you find the pl/sql package and in the line# you find the line number inside of the package.

The sys_b_n are bind variables that Oracle uses instead of the original parameter names in the query.

Answer (score 1):

If that's query you run in your schema, perhaps you could `user_source`

```
select * from user_source
where upper(text) like '%SALDO_EQUIVAL_OUT%');
                         -----------------
                         this might be "unique" enough to return 
                         not-that-many rows as result
```

Here's what you can expect to see (my schema, my search string):

```
SQL> select name, line, substr(text, 1, 40) text
  2  from user_source
  3  where upper(text) like '%DATUM%';

NAME                  LINE TEXT
--------------- ---------- ----------------------------------------
P_INSERT                 5     using (select par_date_from + level
P_INSERT                 9   on (a.dates = b.datum)
P_INSERT                11     values (to_char(b.datum, 'yyyymmdd')
P_INSERT                12             b.datum,
P_INSERT                13             extract(year from b.datum),
P_INSERT                14             'Q' || to_char(b.datum, 'Q')
P_INSERT                15             extract(month from b.datum)

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Now, once you know the source, you can start optimizing it.

Also, see with DBA whether they can (I don't know why not) query `DBA_SOURCE`; that query might, though, run longer as it scans the whole database, but - if you're both desperate enough ... it's worth trying.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have found the SQL ID in `v$sql` (assuming it's still in the cache), check `v$sql_bind_capture`.

Note that Oracle doesn't capture every single bind value and instead uses a sampling algorithm, so you may or may not get the values you are looking for if the query runs frequently with different bind values.